# What tools are available to test JobScheduler?

Tags: android, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

We're implementing a Job via [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) for background loading of data. The job will fire about once a day. What tools are available for us to test this functionality (possibly ADB)?

Use cases are to be able to simulate the conditions required for a Job to be run or to just say specifically "Run this job" as part of our automated test suite.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Right.
Henning and P4u144 set me on the right track to answer this in more detail.

### Identify all registered jobs

Identify your task with the `adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler` command.
This will give you a huge output in following categories.

- Settings
- Registered XX Jobs
- Connectivity
- Alarms
- Idle
- Battery
- AppIdle
- Content
- Job history
- Pending queue

The category you are most likely to be interested in is *Registered XX Jobs*. This tells you how many jobs have been scheduled on the device.
For example, your packagename is `com.foo.bar.application` you should see an entry like this:

```
JOB #u0a93/17: eec3709 com.foo.bar.application/com.evernote.android.job.v21.PlatformJobService
    u0a93 tag=*job*/com.foo.bar.application/com.evernote.android.job.v21.PlatformJobService
    Source: uid=u0a93 user=0 pkg=com.foo.bar.application
    JobInfo:
      Service: com.foo.bar.application/com.evernote.android.job.v21.PlatformJobService
      PERIODIC: interval=+15m0s0ms flex=+5m0s0ms
      PERSISTED
      Requires: charging=false deviceIdle=false
      Network type: 2
      Backoff: policy=1 initial=+30s0ms
      Has early constraint
      Has late constraint
    Required constraints: TIMING_DELAY DEADLINE UNMETERED
    Satisfied constraints: CONNECTIVITY NOT_ROAMING APP_NOT_IDLE DEVICE_NOT_DOZING
    Unsatisfied constraints: TIMING_DELAY DEADLINE UNMETERED
    Earliest run time: 07:23
    Latest run time: 12:23
    Ready: false (job=false pending=false active=false user=true)
```

> Tip: Use `adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler | grep com.foo.bar.application` to quickly filter the list.

Now you can easily identify if your job has been registered with the correct criteria.

### FireBaseJobdispatcher

If you use `FirebaseJobDispatcher` lib you can use

```
adb shell dumpsys activity service GcmService | grep com.foo.bar.debug
    com.foo.bar.debug:0 v853
    u0|com.foo.bar.debug: 3
    (scheduled) com.foo.bar.debug/com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver{u=0 tag="com.foo.bar.debug.job.FetchArticlesJob" trigger=window{start=10800s,end=11700s,earliest=10448s,latest=11348s} requirements=[NET_UNMETERED,DEVICE_IDLE] attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=-351s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=FIREBASE_JOB_DISPATCHER-1}
    (scheduled) com.foo.bar.debug/com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver{u=0 tag="com.foo.bar.debug.job.FetchNotificationGroupsJob" trigger=window{start=86400s,end=129600s,earliest=86048s,latest=129248s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED,CHARGING] attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=-351s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=FIREBASE_JOB_DISPATCHER-1}
    (scheduled) com.foo.bar.debug/com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver{u=0 tag="com.foo.bar.debug.job.RemoveUnusedRealmArticlesJob" trigger=window{start=577980s,end=608400s,earliest=521961s,latest=552381s} requirements=[NET_ANY] attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=-56018s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=FIREBASE_JOB_DISPATCHER-1}
    (finished) [com.foo.bar.debug/com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver:com.foo.bar.debug.job.UpdateNotificationGroupJob,u0]
    (finished) [com.foo.bar.debug/com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver:com.foo.bar.debug.job.UpdatePushTokenJob,u0]
    (finished) [com.foo.bar.debug/com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver:com.foo.bar.debug.job.FetchArticlesJob,u0]
```

to check if your service has been scheduled or run.

### Force your task to run

When creating a `Job` you get a `JOB_ID` returned.
Use this `JOB_ID` to force the job to run.
You can do this by using the `adb shell cmd jobscheduler run` command, (requires Android 7.1 or higher).

For example, your packagename is `com.foo.bar.application` and the `JOB_ID` was 1. 
You can now run your task via `adb`

```
adb shell cmd jobscheduler run -f com.foo.bar.application 1
```

Don't forget the `-f` option as this forces the job to run even if the restrictions set are not met.

### Evernote Android Job Lib

Last but certainly not least.
Use [the wonderful library from Evernote](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) for this.
It allows for easy backporting of the `JobScheduler` on lower API levels using either `JobScheduler`, `GcmNetworkManager` or `AlarmManager` depending on your API level.

### Edit 24/08

Even better use the firebase job dispatcher library.

> The [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) is a library for scheduling background jobs in your Android app. It provides a JobScheduler-compatible API that works on all recent versions of Android (API level 9+) that have Google Play services installed.

I hope this helped.

Thanks

### Edit 28/04/2019

Both [Evernote Android-Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) and [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) are now in maintenance only mode and they both suggest to use jetpack's [WorkManager](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/android-jetpack-workmanager-stable.html) for these kind of jobs.

### Edit 10/06/202

Android Jetpack WorkManager made it slightly easier to diagnose.
First you will need to enable diagnostics for your package

```
adb shell am broadcast -a 'androidx.work.diagnostics.REQUEST_DIAGNOSTICS' -p 'com.foo.bar.application'
```

After that you can WorkManager will dump information in `ADB Logcat` which you can observe by entering.

```
adb logcat
```

Or via Android Studio `Logcat` tool window

Comment: Good summary! I just wanted to add that all you wrote applies to Android 7 and up. JobScheduler is on board since Android 5, there the output is different. Just if anybody wonders.

Comment: In my case, Firebase JobDispatcher used GcmNetworkManager to schedule jobs, even on Android O, instead of platform available JobScheduler -- so I couldn't use this command to force the job to run.

Had to switch to evernote's android-job, which does use platform JobScheduler on api 21+.

Comment: The output does says `Running job [FORCED]` but the job doesn't run. Tested on emulator with with Android O.

Comment: In `JOB #u0a93/17` JOB_ID is 17 ?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar I experience the same with Android 8.1 and 9 (AVD & Device) but it also shuts down logcat output, leaving a blank window. I had to restart AS after that.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar did you solve the problem with Running job [FORCED]?

Comment: @LeandroOcampo Sorry it's being so long that I don't remember exactly.

Comment: there is now a gui tool in Android Studio to analyze the WorkManager:
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#workmanager-inspector

Comment: FYI, your edit "Edit 10/06/202" is missing the 2 at the end for 2022.

Answer (score 19):

// Update:
There is a new GUI tool in Android Studio 2020.3.1: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#workmanager-inspector

// Old answer:
With the command `adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler` you get informations about the currently scheduled and active jobs.

I noticed that the ouput from the command differs greatly between Android 6 and 7. With an **Android 5** device the output is very short and sometimes cryptic. The interesting part with the registered jobs is build [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/JobStatus.java#L221) and repeated below for convenience, which should help with the deciphering:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(hashCode()).substring(0, 3) + ".."
            + ":[" + job.getService()
            + ",jId=" + job.getId()
            + ",u" + getUserId()
            + ",R=(" + formatRunTime(earliestRunTimeElapsedMillis, NO_EARLIEST_RUNTIME)
            + "," + formatRunTime(latestRunTimeElapsedMillis, NO_LATEST_RUNTIME) + ")"
            + ",N=" + job.getNetworkType() + ",C=" + job.isRequireCharging()
            + ",I=" + job.isRequireDeviceIdle() + ",F=" + numFailures
            + ",P=" + job.isPersisted()
            + (isReady() ? "(READY)" : "")
            + "]";
}
```

**Android 7** devices on the other hand have a very long output with more detailed and better readable informations. Also there are more features like a history. The drawback is that you have to find the interesting parts first.

<strike>I haven't found a way to force a job to run though, [there is a feature request for it.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82851)</strike> See the answer from p4u144.

Comment: Henning: The link to the "Android 6" code you have actually points to the lollipop-release branch, which is slightly different from the marshmallow branch's output.

Answer (score 17):

Starting in Android 7.0, there is a new `cmd` for adb shell. And in 7.1 (only in preview right now), the `adb shell cmd jobscheduler` has been added [as you can see here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5d34605) to force run your JobScheduler.
The helps says:

> Job scheduler (jobscheduler) commands:   help
>       Print this help text.
>
> run [-f | --force] [-u | --user USER_ID] PACKAGE JOB_ID
>       Trigger immediate execution of a specific scheduled job.
>       Options:
>         -f or --force: run the job even if technical constraints such as
>            connectivity are not currently met
>         -u or --user: specify which user's job is to be run; the default is
>            the primary or system user

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me, without the need to use adb commands. It requires *minSdk 21*

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public abstract class BaseJobServiceTest {

  protected final Context context() {
    return InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
  }

  protected final void launchJobAndWait(JobInfo jobInfo) throws InterruptedException {
    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

    scheduler.schedule(jobInfo);

    while (jobExecutionPending(scheduler, jobInfo)) {
      Thread.sleep(50);
    }
  }

  private boolean jobExecutionPending(JobScheduler scheduler, JobInfo jobInfo) {
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.N) {
      return scheduler.getPendingJob(jobInfo.getId()) != null;
    }

    List<JobInfo> scheduledJobs = scheduler.getAllPendingJobs();
    for (int i = 0, size = scheduledJobs.size(); i < size; i++) {
      if (scheduledJobs.get(i).getId() == jobInfo.getId()) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: For periodic jobs, won't scheduler.getPendingJob() always return non-null?

Comment: might be the case, I'm not using that right now so I can't say. Maybe there's a way to identify if it's a new JobInfo? I don't know if equals will do the job.

Comment: This is a test class, we want to force the main thread to go to sleep.