# How do I test my JobService with an Instrumentation test?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I have a `JobService` that is properly implemented and works fine in simple cases but I want to ensure the service is properly tested in all conditions.

I'd like to use an Instrumentation test case so that I can test the full flow from the scheduling of the job with `getSystemService(JobScheduler.class).schedule(job)` to the invocation of `onCreate` in my `JobService` and my `onStartJob`/`onStopJob` calls.

My `JobService` launches `AsyncTask`s sometimes (thereby returning `true` in `onStartJob`) and other times it returns `false` for work that's already done. I have various calls to `jobFinished(mJobParameters, needsReschedule)` and I'd like to ensure that they work properly as well.

I've been trying to get instrumentation tests working for the past couple days but the best I've been able to come up with is a test that schedules the job but the job never leaves the pending state. I have tried various configurations of waits/background threads to see if freeing the UI thread is what's needed but haven't had any success.

It also doesn't appear that Google has surfaced anything to properly test the full flow of this component which is surprising, given how they seem to be forcing everyone to use it as newer APIs are released.

I've seen [What tools are available to test JobScheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880969/what-tools-are-available-to-test-jobscheduler) but it's difficult to automate with `adb` (and I'm not interested in answers that use it).

**Does anyone know a way to end to end test a JobService with the JobScheduler using Instrumentation tests?**

Comment: If this isn't getting enough attention, don't forget you can add a bounty to it. (We tend to discourage requests for upvotes in posts here, but at a stretch one could put them in the comments, where they are not a distraction for future readers).

Comment: When I made that edit, the question wasn't eligible for a bounty

Comment: I've opened a feature request with Google about this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62543492

Comment: Why are you trying to be confined to the library implementation? You do not want to test whether the JobScheduler works as expected, right? Because that's not your job. Instead, mock out jobParams and perform assertions on your `AsyncTask`, what's the issue there?

Comment: I want to test how my code and the JobScheduler interact, it's not at all the same as testing that the JobScheduler works. It's no different than desiring to test the full lifecycle of an Activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the Google devs being very responsive to answer my question here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62543492, it's now clear how to do it!

It appears that part of the set up of the instrumentation test examples they provided is setting the running app as active and mostly learning about job state via `cmd jobscheduler <command>` invocations on the shell *from* the test

```
    try {
        SystemUtil.runShellCommand(getInstrumentation(), "cmd activity set-inactive "
                + mContext.getPackageName() + " false");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("ConstraintTest", "Failed setting inactive false", e);
    }
```

See [the provided InstrumentationTestCase subclass they posted in the bug notes](https://doc-08-34-issuetracker.googleusercontent.com/attachments/ov1t2c77tt0go9uoq68tc8gv9h3igveu/lv9d6bnf29mto26lslt76v4g8hraglpq/1497449700000/190602/116079826748296871963/15138426?download=false&nonce=cuinvoenhergg&user=116079826748296871963&hash=spj6r9d22krit19o0g3lepbendttto3l)