# Will Android Firebase Job Dispatcher Trigger by Changing Date Time?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-job-dispatcher

I am using Firebase Job Dispatcher to schedule jobs in Android.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

The job is meant to run in every 12 hours.

Is it possible to test the job by changing date time of the device to a future date?

Like, will the job get triggered after changing the device time to the next day or so?

-- **EDIT** - by the way, I tested like so and the job is not triggered. Is that an expected behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, generally it'll not be triggered - especially on newer droids.

There is much on the web about this, even here - [What tools are available to test JobScheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880969/what-tools-are-available-to-test-jobscheduler)

In short: use `adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler` to obtain list with schedulled jobs, find yours by application Id, and then you can trigger it by `adb shell cmd jobscheduler run` command - take care about job restrictions, or use `-f` to get over them