# adb command to list all scheduled work using workmanager

Tags: android, adb, android-workmanager

Is there a adb shell (dumpsys) command that will give a detailed info of all the tasks scheduled using workmanager - PeriodicWorkRequest

Basically I have a scheduled task which should run daily. How do I get when Is the next task scheduled using adb.

Will `adb shell dumpsys alarm package.name` list my scheduled work using workmanager

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/states-and-observation#observing

Comment: I know that, I want to get the info using adb so that I can see if I scheduled properly

Comment: so override `dump` method like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51915233/2252830) and dump your `WorkInfo` object

Comment: Interesting, will try and see if I get what I want

Answer (score 10):

Given that WorkManager stores all the `WorkRequest` in a Room database, your bet bet is to retrieve that DB and look into it.

For `adb` as far as I know, your best bet is to use what is available for JobScheduler (that WorkManager uses for API Level 23+ devices):

```
adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler
```

as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42133270/118862).

Update January 2020
More information on how to debug WorkManager is now available in the official documentation: [Debugging WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging).

Answer (score 5):

Clear your logcat. Open the terminal. Run adb shell am broadcast -a "androidx.work.diagnostics.REQUEST_DIAGNOSTICS" -p "<your_app_package_name>". Check logcat again. This should work.